# BCM2835 Raspberry Pi 4

Tags: spi, raspberry-pi4

I'm using the library bcm2835 [1](https://www.airspayce.com/mikem/bcm2835/), it works, I can see on the terminal how plots 126 data information from a sensor but from that point on I recieve this:

```
bcm2835_init: gpio mmap failed: Cannot allocate memory
```

Does anyone know what is the problem or how to solve it?I think it's due to the library but not sure how to solve it.
I'm using SPI for reciving the data

```
#include <bcm2835.h>
#include <stdio.h>
char n = 0;

void escriure_csv(char valor){

}
int main()
{   
    FILE * fp;
    fp = fopen ("file.csv", "w+");
    
    for(int i=0;i<130;i++){
    
    bcm2835_init();
    bcm2835_spi_begin();
    
    bcm2835_spi_setBitOrder(BCM2835_SPI_BIT_ORDER_MSBFIRST);
    bcm2835_spi_setDataMode(BCM2835_SPI_MODE0);                   
    bcm2835_spi_setClockDivider(BCM2835_SPI_CLOCK_DIVIDER_1024);
    bcm2835_spi_chipSelect(BCM2835_SPI_CS0);                      
    bcm2835_spi_setChipSelectPolarity(BCM2835_SPI_CS0, LOW);
    
    
    uint8_t send_data = 0xB3; //ens dona igual perque nomès ens interesa el que torna
    uint8_t read_data = bcm2835_spi_transfer(send_data);
    //printf("Read back from SPI: 0x%02X.\n", read_data);
 
    
    //transformem al que volem 
    //els canvis seran mV per lo tant enlloc de *2.5 hi fem fer 2
    uint8_t mV = (read_data*250)/1024; //en cas que tornes un 0 es perque el resultat es - o 0.
    printf("mV: %u\n", mV);
    n+=1;
    fprintf(fp,"%d",mV);
    fprintf(fp,"\n");
    //escriure_csv(mV);
}
    fclose(fp);
    return 0;
}
```

[image]

Comment: Is your program running at root? I faintly remember getting this error message when running with insufficient permissions.

Comment: Yes it is, the fact is that it returns me data but just 125 points, then it appears this.

Comment: https://github.com/nRF24/RF24/issues/517 This might be helpful, in case you haven't already seen it. -- I still vaguely remember getting the same error but can't really remember what the problem was.

Comment: Thanks, I've already seen it, but I don't understand what they say is need to be done...

Comment: Why are you inititializing the SPI on every iteration? Also, if there is initialization, I would assume something would need to be freed too after.

Comment: Did you install the bcm_2835 driver from the package manager or did you download the source and compile it yourself?

Comment: @leppie Thank you a lot! I didn't thought about that!

Comment: @EvaDeltor If it was the answer, please post it as one

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As one of the comments said the problem here was that I was initializinf the SPI every iteration, I had to put it outside the for loop.